# tsconfig reference doesn't seem to work with multiple projects in VS2017 15.7.1

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017, tsconfig

I've got a VS2017 15.7.1 solution with two projects in it.  Project A has an angular.js and an angular.d.ts file in it, which I want to reference in Project B, using the tsconfig.json file, which looks like this:

```
{
  "include": [
    "../ProjectA/angular.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts"
  ]
}
```

In a file.ts in Project B I would now expect to be able to reference the angular namespace (I can reference it fine in the same project), but it says it cannot find the symbol 'angular' in the global module.

However, if I open the same set of projects in VS Code, it behaves exactly how I would expect.  Is this a bug with Visual Studio or am I just mangling something?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured this out.  VS 15.6 changed so that it only recognizes .tsconfig files if their Build Action is set to Content on their properties.